# polygon.contains() returns false value

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapely

I have constructed a `shapely` polygon with the following shape

```
POLYGON ((28 0, 28 68, 44 68, 44 58, 46 0, 38 45, 46 0, 41 34, 46 0, 42 24, 46 0, 46 7, 46 0, 28 0))
```

I wrote a code that checks if a certain point is contained in the polygon. For some reason, the eliminating process of the points does not remove all points outside the polygon.

The output is this:
[the dotted lines represent the polygon corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw8Sd.png)

For example, the point [44.5, 44.5] is outside the polygon yet it is still not eliminated.

```
    def getFieldGridPoints(pitchX, pitchY, poly):
    gridPoints = []
    for i in range(1, pitchX + 1, 1):
        for j in range(1, pitchY + 1, 1):
            gridPoints.append(geometry.Point(i - 0.5, j - 0.5))
    finalGrid = []
    for p in gridPoints:
        if poly.contains(p):
            finalGrid.append([p.x, p.y])
    print(finalGrid)
    return finalGrid
```

The code executed after `getFieldGridPoints` only takes into consideration the gridpoints in `finalGrid`. Since the point e.g. 44.5, 44,5 is not eliminated, the coloring process takes place.

a singular call for `poly.contains(p)` with `p = geometry.Point(44.5,44.5)` returns `False`. So I dont understand why it is not eleminated in the loop

Answer (score 0):

The fifth corner of the Polygon is not correct. That is why it is not plotting correctly. Problem fixed.

with `POLYGON ((28 0, 28 68, 44 68, 44 58, 38 45, 46 0, 41 34, 46 0, 42 24, 46 0, 46 7, 46 0, 28 0))` it worked.